# Install python-glpk

Tags: software-installation

I want to install `python-glpk` 
I followed the instructions here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Python

But when I tried to do this:

```
import glpk
print glpk.glp_version()
```

I have these errors

[image]

Thank you

Comment: It is known bug in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, see fix in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bug

For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it is known issue - it was reported to LaunchPad.net on 2016-10-02 as [bug 1629672](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-glpk/+bug/1629672).

## Fix

We can fix this bug by installation of previous version of `python-ply` component with `pip` into your home folder:

```
#sudo apt-get install python-glpk # you did this before in question
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install ply==3.4 --user
```

And then test it with simple script (name it `glpk_test.py`) with contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import glpk
print glpk.glp_version()
```

then make it executable with `chmod +x glpk_test.py` and execute with `./glpk_test.py`.

The output on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will be:

> ```
> 4.57
> ```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the quick response
I did it, but nothing happend.

The steps that I followed to install are:

1) sudo apt-get install python-glpk
2) sudo apt-get install glpk-utils
3) sudo apt-get install python-pip
4) pip install ply==3.4 --user

Am I right?

Comment: Just tested this method on my fully upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - it results in 4.57 with these steps.